# Resizing UITableview for iphone 5 screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cgrect

I have a method which is called from other methods to resize the size of a UITableView. However, the table view is only resized the second time this code gets called not the first time as I thought it would. I have also confirmed that this method is getting called both time by using NSLog. The method which resizes the table view is below.

```
-(void) resizeTableView
{
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        NSLog(@"Resizing table view");
        CGRect tableFrame = [self.tableView frame];
        tableFrame.size.height = 210.0;
        [self.tableView setFrame:tableFrame];
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can change this code so it would resize the table view every time. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Where are you calling this method from? Make sure it is being called from viewWillAppear. If you call it in the viewDidLoad method self.view.frame will always be 0,0,0,0

Comment: I was having this same issue and moving it to the viewWillAppear did not change anything. The function is called but the size of the table is not changed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I actually fixed it by putting it in the "viewDidAppear". Thanks for your answer, helped me to figure it out.

Comment: @Donovan if it helped then accept the answer :-) This way others who have the problem will see the problem has been answered and can see how to maybe solve theirs.

Comment: this was not my question so I cannot answer. I did vote your answer up however.

Comment: @Donovan My apologies. Should have noticed.